# Algorithm for polygon color subdivision per each edge

Tags: algorithm

**PROBLEM**

Im working on displaying results of some simulation analysis. It is basically polygon surface model with assigned color for each verticle representing pressure/temperature/deformation/whatever the simulation is calculating (see picture below). 
There are already too many verticles which is causing performance issues. But we need more resolution on areas that matter - those verticles that are actually part of several color areas. This way would like to increase resolution but at the same time keep polygon count low (we are doing some demanding model conversion on the way so doing higres first and then decimation is not an option).

Therefore during export we would like to create smart subdivision of verticles and create additional colored verticles where it matters. As one polygon can be part of up to 4 color areas on each edge, I am looking for algorithm that will help me create this subdivision.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vr8I.jpg) shows polygon net versus simulation coloring results. Ideally polygons should copy those colors.

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Y1e.jpg) shows my ideas about possible division. We are not able to detect exact location of color change, only sampling at verticles is possible, therefore we only have information to how many colors each edge will be divided.

**SOLUTION**

INPUT:

- one polygon spatial + color information
- information about new color subdivision, i.e. edge I-J will need 3 color subdivision, I-K 2 subdivision, etc. Exact colors will be calculated from rainbow

OUTPUT:

- multiple polygons = spatial information + calculated intermediate colors on verticle level
- practically we can limit ourselves to 4 colors per edge max

**QUESTION**

- programming language of this is something proprietary so I am looking rather for pseudocode or general concept
- please can you help me with approach to this algorithm? I know here must be something done already but i was unable to find anything useful

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly... So you have a 2D surface where each point can take one in a discrete set of values and you want to find points where the values change and build polygons from it? But then how do you already know how many subdivisions you need on each edge?

Comment: Actually it is 3D model in in floating point x,y,z coordinates for each triangle. Those triangles are turned to polygons later in processing (adding normals). Purpose of this exercise is to process polygon in this mesh and subdivide (create more triangles) if needed.
We already have testing function that will decide how many more points on each edge will be needed. But we need to smartly calculate points of new triangles. 

Did it answer your question?

Comment: Hi, here is (quick and dirty) solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/2u0m4zr0/